# I'm trying to fetch my data from firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

It does work cus i'm seeing

```
I/flutter (10071): [{quantity: 7, price: 4, name: Ayam Masah Merak, recipe: Ayam, Chilli, id: c5f935b0-538d-11eb-acb5-4d9f82c74017, category: food, picture: [https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/aizadfyp2021final.appspot.com/o/images%2F2021-01-10%2021%3A49%3A51.509046?alt=media&token=85605972-86da-4747-96ac-baa0abd5fe3a]}]
```

but at my phone it shows 'no data'. What did I do wrong? the code:

```
return FutureBuilder(
  future: Global.productsRef.getData() , // this one too, yea
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasData) {
        List<Product> products = snapshot.data;
        return GridView.builder( // reload please, amazing
          itemCount: products.length,
          gridDelegate:
          new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {

            return Single_prod(
              prod_name: products[index].name,
              prod_picture: products[index].picture[0],
              prod_price: products[index].price,
              product: products[index] ,
            );
          },
        );
      } else
        return Text('no data');
    });
```

Comment: Could you also share the code for `Global.productsRef.getData()`?

Comment: And I am assuming you saw no errors?

Comment: there's no error but after adding 1 more products, it say no data

i can just add 1 product

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the error. Could I see the implementation of `Global.productsRef.getData() `?